# CSVHelper Inline Convert issue

Tags: c#, inline, converters, csvhelper

Trying to do a GTFS import to my custom type. The C# field is TimeSpan and I am trying to use inline the TimeSpanConverter and am missing something.  I do not need fancy examples of JSON examples. Just need to know how to use the converter inline.

I have researched, looked for examples, tried a class with inheritance from TimeSpanConverter. Not ready for the jason complexe datatypes just a simple inline string (08:00:00)to a TimeSpan on importing

```
        var timeSpanConverter = new CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TimeSpanConverter();


        Map(m => m.trip_id).Name("trip_id");
        Map(m => m.arrival_time).Name("arrival_time").ConvertUsing(timeSpanConverter.ConvertFromString());

        Map(m => m.departure_time).Name("departure_time");
```

Class fields are

public TimeSpan arrival_time { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan departure_time { get; set; }

Line that fails is
 Map(m => m.arrival_time).Name("arrival_time").ConvertUsing(timeSpanConverter.ConvertFromString());

error is:
SCS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'text' of 'TimeSpanConverter.ConvertFromString(string, IReaderRow, MemberMapData)'

hope to have the correct syntax to move forward with my efforts.

Thank you all in advance,

Steve

Comment: If your CSV has a string that is a `Timespan` and your class property is a `Timespan`, you don't need to do anything. CsvHelper will convert it for you using the `TimeSpanConverter`. CsvHelper already has default converters registered for classes like `int`, `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`. You would use `.TypeConverter<TimeSpanConverter>()` if you wanted to change from the default converter.

Answer (score 0):

CsvHelper has default converters registered for most of the types you would be converting to, including `TimeSpan`.  If you are happy with the default, you don't need to do anything.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("trip_id,arrival_time,departure_time");
        writer.WriteLine("101,08:00:00,09:00:00");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int trip_id { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan arrival_time { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan departure_time { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to do something beyond the default, then you can create your own converter and use it.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("trip_id,arrival_time,departure_time");
        writer.WriteLine("101,08:00:00,09:00:00");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Add30SecondsConverter : TimeSpanConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        var timespan = (TimeSpan)base.ConvertFromString(text, row, memberMapData);

        return timespan.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
    }
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.trip_id);
        Map(m => m.arrival_time).TypeConverter<Add30SecondsConverter>();
        Map(m => m.departure_time);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int trip_id { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan arrival_time { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan departure_time { get; set; }
}
```